# How to center a bunch of horizontal views in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` that fills the width of the device and it contains several `UIViews` laid out horizontally. The views all have the same width, so on the iPhone one has to scroll to see all the views, but on the iPad all of the views are visible.

My question is how can I perfectly horizontally center the views on screen? When the available space is large enough to display all views, they need to be centered but when it's not large enough to display all views they can be laid out as they are now, simply left to right.

The interface has been set up entirely in Interface Builder. The scroll view is set to fill the entire device width - leading and trailing to superview. The first view in the scroll view has leading set to its superview so it's stuck to the far left. The last button has its trailing set to the superview - to the far right of the scroll view, to define the scrollable content area. Each view in the middle is laid out relative to the view to the left of it - leading to the previous button.

Here's a graphical representation of the current layout:
[image]

Here's a graphical representation of what I'd like to obtain:
[image]

Additional info:
The scroll view doesn't have to always fill the device width, as it is actually completely transparent. When all views are visible I want to disable scrolling. This will need to be adaptive, such that upon rotating the device it can change the layout if needed, because on iPhone in landscape all the views should be visible but in portrait they won't be.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `contentInset` property on the scroll view, computing how much space you need on both sides? (The space you have off to the right, divided by 2.)

Comment: @CraigOtis I haven't. That sounds promising, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @CraigOtis That did the trick! Super simple, care to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the `contentInset` property of the scroll view, which has a type of `UIEdgeInsets`. This property simply provides the scroll view with a certain amount of "padding", adding to the scrollable area.

You can determine how much extra space you have at the end (right-hand side) of your view, divide it by 2, and use that value to provide equal-width padding on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Another purely autolayout-based approach could be:

- Constrain your middle view to be horizontally centered in the superview.
- Constrain each view relative to the middle view in a chain